# ASP.NET: Get correct url to uploaded image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I upload images like this:

```
private const string ProfilePicturesUploadDir = "~/_useruploads/ProfilePictures/";

var fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid()+Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ProfilePicturesUploadDir), fileName));
```

I want to retrieve the correct image in my view code. I am trying this:

```
 public static string GetProfilePictureUrl(string profilePicture)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ProfilePicturesUploadDir + profilePicture);
        }
```

and then

```
 <img src="@FileService.GetProfilePictureUrl(Model.ProfilePicture)" width="250" height="250" />
```

But it gives me a 404: Not found.

What should I do?
Can I do this better?

Comment: Is profilePicture parameter is going with extension of picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
@Url.Content(ProfilePicturesUploadDir)
```

to get the URL of the folder.

Comment: How does that work?  Isn't `ProfilePicturesUploadDir` just a virtual path to a directory?  Shouldn't it be `@Url.Content(FileService.GetProfilePictureUrl(Model.ProfilePicture))`