# How do I make an Image File to an ImageUrl in VB ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am currently making a site that a user uploads images. I am stuck though. When the user picks the file, file upload is open, but I cannot convert the image file to an ImageUrl. The code is

```
Public Class WebForm2
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Image1.ImageUrl = FileUpload1.PostedFile
  End Sub


End Class
```

The problem is the website, needs an image URL rather than a file. If there is a way to find or make an image url for the file uploaded

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please post the code you've tried and explain further.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395829/asp-net-get-correct-url-to-uploaded-image)

Comment: You need to save the file on the server first, then you can make a link to it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you make a server.

Comment: What do you mean? You've already got a webserver, otherwise how are you running this code? Just save the file to the disk on the machine where the asp.net code is running. It needs to be somewhere in a folder publicly available through the server though. In asp.net you could just make an "images" folder inside the project, and save it there.

Comment: Oh thanks. Sorry I am new to this ASP.NET thing.

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to display the just uploaded image

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" & FileUpload1.FileName))
Image1.ImageUrl = "/Content/Images/" & uplOne.FileName
```

You might need to create the Images folder.